# Computer too slow

Tags: windows-vista

I am using Windows Vista Home Premium 64 bit in my HCL Beanstalk machine with 1 GB RAM.  The processor is Core 2 Duo. But my system has become too slow to work. "Not Responding" messages have become frequent. It gets stuck whenever i try to open any application. It shows up even if i open My Computer. I have formatted my machine 3 times but the problem still exists. I tried to install windows xp but the audio driver was not working so i had to reinstall Windows Vista.
Also want to know if system problem can affect broadband connection as the connection gets lost many times in a day.

Comment: It sounds like your HDD is failing if reinstalling your operating system does resolve performance related problems.

Comment: I'd use a lightweight user friendly linux distro on that pc, vista is the worst desktop windows ever made, and you're using it on a 1 GB ram machine!

Comment: Your computer is simply old. Vista needs at least 3 GB RAM to work with reasonable performance, not to mention other components. You can try installing Windows 8 to boost it a bit, but don't expect miracles.

Comment: Did your computer work fine in the past? If it did you can ignore all RAM/memory comments because that is not the problem. (Having said that: adding a few GB of memory will speed things up and is cheap. But if the computer *recently* started showing those problems then there is most likely another problem.  One of the likely candidates for new problems on older but reinstalled machines has already been mentioned: A failing HDD. Check the eventviewer for messages which can confirm that (or which can show something completely different).  (Start, run, `eventvwr.msc`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best and cheapest ways to improve performance on a PC is to increase the RAM.  I would try installing 2 GB of RAM and see if that helps at all.  If not, I would suggest backing up your data as soon as you can and get a new hard drive. As Ramhound said, it is also very likely your HDD is failing.  Also, you could try running Disk Defragmentor which comes with Windows systems.  This will rearrange the data on the HDD closer together to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Vista is very hardware hungry and required an unreasonable amount of RAM and processing power to run efficiently. Now with more modern computers that wouldnt be a problem but your machine only has 1gb of RAM and im sure Vista uses about 660mb of that, I could imagine you dont have the most powerful processor in there either. This doesnt leave much left over to run other applications, or do much at all really.

I think you should update some of your machine hardware like the RAM and the processor or better yet build or purchase a newer more powerful machine which comes with windows 7.

Times are hard for everyone right now though so if buying one isnt an option then go back to re-installing XP, try and find the correct sound drivers online as well as the drivers for all your other hardware and you should be good to go and much better off than with Vista.

Microsoft are aware Vista was a terrible operating system hense its relatively short lifespan compared to windows XP

Comment: I disagree with both statements. Many people found vista horrible because it was new and *different*.  After they got used to it win7 was fine, and win7 is very close to vista with SP1.  Also win7 runs fine on netbooks with 1GB RAM. The posted computer is probably a lot faster than that. I suspect that the problem is either malware or some hardware problem (such as a failing HDD)).

Comment: @Hennes +1 Vista/7 have the same requirements and often Vista uses less RAM for me compared to 7. Nice to see that some users here have such a deep understanding and don't post such nonsense :)

Comment: a clean install of windows XP on a 32 bit system uses around 120MB of RAM while both windows Vista and Windows 7 use over 500MB more than that. His system (only having a core 2 duo processor and 1GB of RAM definintely isnt that fast and it is no secret that 1GB of RAM running Windows Vista is a big ask. I would at least increase to 2GB. without debating about which is the best operating system, the answer to the original question is his machine is far too weak to run windows Vista and should either be upgraded or the operating system changed to XP

Comment: my HDD temp is around 56 degree C as its kept in a box. Can this afeect my system's performance( my monitor screen does go black on summer days)? Also I installed HD Tune to check for bad sectors in my disc but could not find any. I am unable to work out whether it is because of RAM or any other hardware component is not functioning properly. And this problem is not recent. Its been around 1.5 yr @Karan. I have formatted it around 3-4 times.

Comment: Do whatever you can to keep your machine as cool as possible. If you have always had this problem i stand by my original answer stating that your machine is just too weak to run Vista. the vast majority of your computer hardware is being taken up by the operating system leaving you with almost nothing left to do anything else